# How many Google analytics segments can I create?

Tags: google-analytics

What is the total number of segments a person can have?  I was told once that the number was 1000/user that were visible in any segment and 100/user visible in a specific view.

Are those numbers correct?

Does that mean I can have 100 segments in every view I create or is the total number of segments visible to only one view max out at 100 regardless of the view they are limited to?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, numbers are correct. Check the Google official guide https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3123951?hl=en

A user can have:

- 1000 segments that can be applied/edited in any view, plus
- 100 segments that can be applied/edited only by that user in only View A, plus
- 100 segments that can be applied/edited only by that user in only View B

A view can have:

- 100 segments per user that can be applied/edited only by that user in that view
- 100 segments that can be applied/edited by any user in only that view

As a user, you can have 1000 in any view plus 100 for each specific view. So 1000 + (number of views * 100). Just keep in mind that you can't use all of them in all views.

> You cannot create or import additional segments once you reach these limits.

Comment: So I could almost have an unlimited number of segments I spread them out correctly?

Comment: Yes, it's hard to reach the limit